# nginix installation with custom openssl on mac - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, ssl, nginx

Trying to install nginx on mac machine with the below commands.

```
./configure --prefix=. --sbin-path=nginx_mac/nginx --conf-path=nginx_mac/nginx.conf --error-log-path=nginx_mac/error.log --pid-path=nginx_mac/nginx.pid --lock-path=nginx_mac/nginx.lock --with-pcre=../pcre-8.40 --without-http_rewrite_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/Users/nbbuild/CA5/openssl-1.0.2d
make
```

After I run make it throws below error:

```
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
    make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Not sure what is causing this issue. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: See if this helps http://hanoian.com/content/index.php/23-compile-nginx-with-openssl-on-mac-os-x-64-bit

Comment: Please show some of the symbols not found. Please show how you built OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try the above steps and let you know the result. Between, is there any nginx .dmg installer for mac ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same errors. Try replace the following line in `./objs/Makefile` after running `make`.

Before:

```
&& ./config --prefix=/Users/macbook/Downloads/nginx-1.13.5/../openssl-1.0.2l/.openssl no-shared no-ssl3 \
```

After:

```
&& ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/Users/macbook/Downloads/nginx-1.13.5/../openssl-1.0.2l/.openssl no-shared no-ssl3 \
```

And then run `make` again. Don't run `./configure` because it overwrites that changes. FYI, I found this solution here: https://www.widlabs.com/article/mac-os-x-nginx-compile-symbol-not-found-for-architecture-x86_64.

I hope this helps you.